# react native setInterval fires too fast (using expo)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I made a timer hook for react native which counts from `from` props to `to` props. It returns the current value of timer in seconds, `start` function, `stop` function, `restart` function and `pause` function in an object. Here is the timer code:

```
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'react'

export default function useTimer({ from, to, intervalS, finished }) {
    const [timer, setTimer] = useState(from)
    const interval = useRef()

    const start = () => {
        if (!interval.current) {
            interval.current = setInterval(() => {
                setTimer(timer => timer - intervalS)
            }, intervalS * 1000)
        }
    }

    const pause = () => {
        clearInterval(interval.current)
        interval.current = null
    }

    const stop = () => {
        clearInterval(interval.current)
        interval.current = null
        setTimer(from)
    }

    const restart = () => {
        clearInterval(interval.current)
        interval.current = null
        setTimer(from)
        start()
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            clearInterval(interval.current)
        }
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        if (timer === to) {
            finished()
            clearInterval(interval.current)
        }
    }, [timer])

    return {
        value: timer,
        start,
        pause,
        restart,
        stop
    }
}
```

Everything works perfectly but when i try to render (or even `console.log`) the timer value, it counts faster than what should be. For example the timer will pass 20 seconds for every 15 seconds in real time. I am using `Expo Go` app for development and my device is an android phone. Am i doing something wrong? Here is how i use timer:

```
export default function Countdown() {
    const [finished, setFinished] = useState(false)
    const timer = useTimer({ from: 60, to: 0, intervalS: 1, finished: () => setFinished(true) })

    return (
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Typography variant="heading">{timer.value}</Typography>
                <Button title="start" onPress={timer.start} />
                <Button title="pause" onPress={timer.pause} />
                <Button title="restart" onPress={timer.restart} />
                <Button title="stop" onPress={timer.stop} />
            </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: Incrementing or decrementing a counter is just the wrong approach to tracking time. Instead you want to store the time the time started counting down and calculate the remaining time based on the current time. Your approach can get vastly out of sync if the computer is under heavy load and setinterval runs infrequently. This is a very clean implementation, it is an excellent first pass!

Comment: Then how freqeuently should i get the current time? Shouldn't i use `setInterval` still?

Comment: You can still use set interval, but this `setTimer(timer => timer - intervalS)`  approach where you add or subtract from number inside setInterval will eventually drift and be incorrect. Instead you need to store the start time and calculate the difference between that and the current time.

Comment: Hmm, i got the point. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone who might be wondering what's wrong, the problem is with expo's development mode. I don't know why but it seems timing is faster in expo's development mode. Just toggle the development mode to production mode and time will become normal

Comment: The same issue happened to me for setInterval even if not using expo, I used react native

Answer (score 1):

I used this approach to create a timer before:

```
const [intervalID, setIntervalID] = useState<any>(null)
//Initially set to 60 secs
const [testTime, setTestTime] = React.useState(60)

useEffect(() => {
    setIntervalID(setInterval(() => {
        updateTimer();
    }, 1000));

    return () => clearInterval(intervalID);
}, [])

useEffect(() => {
    if (testTime <= 0) {
        //Timer hit zero

        return () => clearInterval(intervalID)
    }
}, [testTime])

const updateTimer = () => {
    setTestTime(testTime => testTime - 1)
}

function displayTime(seconds) {
    const format = val => `0${Math.floor(val)}`.slice(-2)
    const minutes = (seconds % 3600) / 60

    return [minutes, seconds % 60].map(format).join(':')
}

const getRemainingTime = () => {
    let finalTime = displayTime(testTime)
    return <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>{finalTime} minutes left</Text>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with my Expo app.

Just disable "Debug Remote JS" for it to work!